# Screen rotation not available in Display settings. How to get it back?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I'm running OSX 13.5 on a MacBook Pro. I use DisplayLink Manager to handle connecting 2 external screens via an Anker hub.

I've got an external screen which can rotate. I've used this screen, in the past, rotated, in portrait mode, but have not for the past few months.

My setup changed today, and I want to use this screen in portrait mode again.

However, in Display Settings, I no longer have the option to specify that I've got this screen rotated.

Meanwhile, my second external screen *does* have the option to set it to being rotated.

How do I get the option back to specify that this screen is rotated?

MBP: 16-inch, 2021

Display 1 (connected directly, has the option to rotate): Samsung AU7700

Display 2 (connected to the hub, no option to rotate): HP ZR2440W

Hub: Anker (not seeing a model number on the device)

DisplayLink Manager: 1.9.0

Comment: What model of MBP , and what displays? The first thing to try is to connect each display directly, instead of through the hub. If the rotation options don't appear when used through the hub, or through DisplayLink Manager, then that's the problem.

Comment: That was my first thought, too. But, connecting the problematic display directly also didn't give me the rotation option. Adding the models to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using DisplayLink Manager to connect multiple devices, the option might not display at all in the Mac settings. However, if you open the DisplayLink manager app, (top right of your screen, the overlaping squares), it should give you the option to choose the rotation for the display.

Comment: Thanks. Surprised I missed this when I had the problem initially. But this is the best solution for my setup.

Answer (score 2):

Screen rotation appears to be hidden on some displays, including the built-in Retina display on my 2021 MacBook Pro. I was able to force macOS to display the rotation option by doing the following:

- Hold the Option key on your keyboard
- Launch System Settings via the drop-down menu from the menu bar behind the Apple logo
- While still holding the Option key, navigate to the Displays pane

The rotation should now be visible.

Comment: Interesting! That did do the trick for my built-in display, but not for the external one.

Comment: But! Doing the same while this screen is plugged in directly to my MBP, the rotation button has appeared. Nice.

Comment: I am unable to do this on my MacBook m2